# how to manage two route for one page in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, api, routes

I have one page in angular 1 for Leave workflow and i want to use it for two different routes! hourly leave and daily leave. some component in page is changed by hourly or daily state. how can i do it?

```
    one page 'Leave.html' for tow route:
    www.....com/leave/hourly
    www.....com/leave/daily
```

can i use current path in controller ,split and get last part , then use last keyword in switch case for 'hourly' and 'daily'?

is there a way with angular route?

thanks

Comment: What do you use for routing in your  app ??

Comment: my coworker uses it for routing of site. but every page has one route. and I dont know how can i use it for 2 routes with same html page. i dont want to pass number as parameter. i want to have two different route ../ hourly and '../daily'

Comment: Is urlparams an option? For example: `host.com/leave?hourly=true`. You then access it from angular's route params object.

Comment: A url in it's nature is a nested route. So `host.com/leave/hourly` means: Unless you wanna treat `leave/hourly` as one path, and `leave` is a path of its own, the process is: Get host.com, from host.com get leave, from leave get hourly. So if you do insist on doing so, you should simply add a `ng-outlet` in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ngRoute

```
$routeProvider
.when("/dashboard",
{
    templateUrl: "dashboard.html",
    controller: "dashboardController"
})
.when("/leave/:leaveMode",
{
    templateUrl: "Leave.html",
    controller: "leaveController"
})
.otherwise(
{
    redirectTo: "/dashboard",
    controller: "dashboardController"
});
```

Inside the `leavecontroller` you can access the leaveMode using `$routeParams`

```
$routeParams.leaveMode
```

If the url is `www.....com/leave/hourly`, the `$routeParams.leaveMode` value will be `hourly`

If the url is `www.....com/leave/daily`, the `$routeParams.leaveMode` value will be `daily`

So inside the controller you can use the following sample logic

```
$scope.isHourly = false;
if($routeParams.leaveMode == "hourly"){
    $scope.isHourly = true;
}
```

in html and js you can show/hide componenents or do any logics using the boolean value of `$scope.isHourly`

Comment: thanks for answering. i use ``.when("/leave/:leaveMode",{...}`` and  i try to inject ``module PortalApp {
    class LeaveController extends BaseController {routeParam: ng.route.IRouteParamsService; 
 constructor( _routeParam: ng.route.IRouteParamsService){ this.routeParam = _routeParam;}
isHourly = this.LeaveMode == "hourly" ? true : false; }`` in 'leaveController' .but when i run my project, it shows in concole **TypeError: Cannot read property 'leaveMode' of undefined**. how can i solve this problem? thanks

Comment: which version of angularjs/angular you are using?

Comment: angularJs or angular1

Comment: using ngRouter or ui-router ?

Comment: ngRoute,it has injected by $routeProvider in app.routes.ts

Comment: i think you are not using angularjs. As typescript is involved it can be angular2, angular4 or angular5. If you can share the exact angular version, can help further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166800/discussion-between-smo-and-nishanth).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the last part `/hourly` or `/daily` as a route parameter to your page `/leave`

check out this link to know more about passing optional parameters : [link](http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters)